# Authenticity error when trying to install Rebar

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, rebar, rebar3

I'm using Elixir 1.8.1 and am now seeing this error under our Gitlab CI:

```
* creating /root/.mix/archives/hex-2.0.6
* creating /root/.mix/rebar
** (Mix) Could not install Rebar because Mix could not verify authenticity of metadata file at "https://repo.hex.pm/installs/rebar3-1.x.csv". This may happen because a proxy or some entity is interfering with the download or because you don't have a public key to verify the download.
You may try again later or check if a new public key has been released in our public keys page: https://repo.hex.pm/installs/public_keys.html
```

Exactly 2.5h ago this was running fine:

```
* creating /root/.mix/archives/hex-2.0.6
* creating /root/.mix/rebar
* creating /root/.mix/rebar3
```

There has been no changes on our side.

Is this a Gitlab problem, a new version of rebar3 that got released just now, or an issue in the hex repo?

*UPDATE*: seems like it's on hex's side:

- Issue: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12615
- Linked forum thread: https://elixirforum.com/t/error-installing-rebar3/56160

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Elixir people: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12615. No changes required on our side.